# What's the matter with Captain Boomerang's pink unicorn?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, props, suicide-squad

When preparing for their first mission, the [*Suicide Squad*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386697/) are given access to their personal belongings. Among the various weapons and custom outfits, there's also a pink unicorn plush toy that apparently belongs to Captain Boomerang and which he hides inside his jacket. He also drops it, likely by accident, during battle later on but then picks it up again and puts it back into his jacket.

I wonder **what's the matter with this plush toy**, though. Now of course it first of all seems to be an obvious comedic element (as is his entire character) when having this rugged guy care for such a cutesie little pinky plushy, possibly also adding to his crazy character. But given I'm not the biggest expert on DC comics, let alone Captain Boomerang, **I might as well be missing some reference here**, either to his comics origins or other possibly out-of-universe matters.

So **was this just random throwaway craziness** or is the inclined expert on the Suicide Squad, it's film's production, or pop-culture in general, able to gain more out of that little unicorn's appearance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It was something of a mascot.

David Ayer believed that Boomerang needed something fun to lighten the mood of his character.

> “I thought [Boomerang] needed a little something kind of fun and silly and it kept appearing throughout the film. It became a bit of a mascot,” Ayer then explained, telling fans the unicorn was meant to represent all things George “Digger” Harkness. The villain was particularly fond of the stuffed animal, enough so for him to even take Pinky into battle and beyond.
> <sub>*- [Suicide Squad Director Reveals Story Behind Boomerang's Pink Plush Unicorn - Comicbook.com]*</sub>

It's never confirmed that it is based on the character from my little pony but their names are quite similar.

> Suicide Squad doesn’t explicitly connect the baddie’s unicorn to the animated series, but Pinky does share a very similar name to the show’s character Pinkie Pie. And, of course, pink unicorns are kind of commonplace in the friendly town of Ponyville.
> <sub>*- [Suicide Squad Director Reveals Story Behind Boomerang's Pink Plush Unicorn - Comicbook.com]*</sub>

So, it represented some of Boomerang's other hobbies that weren't robbing banks. **Some fans believe that this was a rip-off of Deadpool** who has a toy unicorn of his own but, Ayer never mentioned this.

Answer (score 6):

According to [an interview](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/suicide-squad-spoilers/) with Director David Ayer and Empire magazine:

> "[Pinky] was actually intended to be a piece of set decoration in one of our office building sets. I thought [Boomerang] needed a little something kind of fun and silly and it kept appearing throughout the film. It became a bit of a mascot. Yes, [he’s a] Brony. Which is fine. I think it’s a good thing and gives him a little hobby besides robbing banks."

Answer (score 0):

It was some kind of talisman.
David Ayer believed that the Boomerang needed something fun to cheer up his character.
"I thought [Boomerang] needed something fun and stupid, and it kept popping up throughout the movie. It became something of a mascot, "Ayer explained, telling fans that the unicorn had to represent all of George Digger Harkness' stuff. The villain was particularly fond of a stuffed animal, sufficient to ensure that he even took Pinky into the battle and not only.

Comment: You might want to add where you have this information and this interview from. Also, I'm not entirely sure what this adds to the already existing answers.